# What's the area of the smaller rectangle?

Tags: geometry

[image]

I tried using x+2 as the longer side of the large unshaded rectangle, and subtracted the right triangles to get 192. My friend tells me this is incorrect, and I was wondering how to get the correct answer.

Comment: Use Pythagorean theorem wisely

Comment: Hint: the triangle with sides $2$ and $6$ is similar to the triangle with sides $9$ and $l$, where $l$ is the horizontal distance over to where the rectangle hits the bottom edge.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

By the Pythagorean theorem, we can clearly see that $EF = 2\sqrt{10}$. Also, note that $\triangle EAF \sim \triangle FBG$, so $\frac{AF}{EF} = \frac{BG}{FG}$, meaning that $\frac{2}{2\sqrt{10}} = \frac{9}{FG}$, which means $FG = 9\sqrt{10}$. We know that the sides of the rectangle are $EF = 2\sqrt{10}, $$ \space FG = 9\sqrt{10}$, thus the area is $9\cdot2\cdot10 =180$.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

$\triangle CAB \sim \triangle EDC \implies DE = 27 $

The other lengths shown are easy to compute.

$area \square ADFG = 29 \cdot 15 =435$

The sum of the areas of the two smaller triangles is $6 \cdot 2 = 12$

The sum of the areas of the two larger triangles is $9 \cdot 27 = 243$

The area of the inscribed rectangle is $435 - 243 - 12 = 180$

Answer (score 1):

Just use the Pythagorean theorem and find the sides of the shaded rectangle:
[image]